# JMeter - Conditionals and Assertions

Tags: jmeter

I am able to have my test plan set up as so: Thread Group > While Controller > SOAP/XML-RPC Request > CSV Data Set Controller & Response Assertion.  When I have one element it is ok, but when I loop through a CSV I get failed.

How do you loop through a CSV (that contains the input parameter values I want to test with) and set an assertion for each please?

E.g. I want to test a currency converter.  My Excel sheet contains these rows:
USD,EUR
EUR,GBP
GBP,USD

The jmeter test plan will loop through my Excel and inject each of those parameter pairs to my web service.  USD,EUR should return 0.9216, EUR,GBP should return 0.729 etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the 'CSV Data Set Config' in this post. If it does not clarify, please let me know with your question.

http://www.testautomationguru.com/how-to-test-rest-api-using-jmeter/

Comment: Hi Vinoth thanks for your response.  I have tried something similar to that post with a free calculator web service that I found.  My csv contains value1,value2,result with a number of rows, e.g. 1,2,3.  The web service will therefore add 1 + 2 and result is 3.  As a response in JMeter I am getting that the result is 3, here is an extract "<AddResult>3</AddResult></AddResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>".  But my assertionResponse fails :( I will update my question

Comment: @Dragonfly, finally you got the response as you wanted. How do you do the assertion?

Comment: Actually I just managed!  I was putting in the result value of '3' in my csv, but in reality the comparison is to the whole response.  Therefore I put the whole response string as my expected result and the response assertion works fine!  Ideally I would prefer if I could just match the return value of '3' instead of the whole SOAP response as it would look neater.  Thanks for the tips in that url though :)

Comment: @Dragonfly, You do not need to compare the whole response. Are you using 'Response Assertion'? You can select the option to look only for the pattern to be checked.

Comment: Yes you're right.  Just updated the Assertion with Pattern Matching Rules "Contains" and updated my results to contain just the tag containing the result like so: value1,value2,result
1,2,<AddResult>3</AddResult>
-2,-2,<AddResult>-4</AddResult>
-3,3,<AddResult>0</AddResult>